# Will SSIS package developed in VS 2010 run on SQL Server 2012 environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

Will SSIS package developed in Visual Studio 2010 run on SQL Server 2012 environment? I'm trying to create a new package in VS 2010 but the server runs SQL Server 2012 will it work ?

Comment: You could create a small package and try that out, and see if you get issues?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure yes it will as 2012 is backwards compatible.  But @christiandev is correct, try a small/simple package and try it.